# add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ) in conflict with custom titles function

Tags: title

'[Title-tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag)' is a theme feature introduced in Version 4.1, and I want to use it as the default title of my theme. This feature should be added on the `after_setup_theme` or `init` action. It is recommended [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/). The use of this feature works perfect for me. BUT:

Moreover, I have a custom titles function which can be enabled/disabled using the Option-Tree framework. This framework is loaded directly in `functions.php`. Then, I have the rest of the functions added on the `after_setup_theme` with priority 2:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_functions', 2);
```

And this is the filter added for my custom titles:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_titles', 10, 2 );
```

When I disable my `custom_titles()` function, the new feature `title-tag` works perfect, but when I enable the custom ones, it returns the title twice. Exactly that:

```
<title>Front page meta title example</title>

Front page meta title example<title></title>
```

The first one is correct, and it's using the `wp_title()` function inserted in the `header.php` between the `title` tags, but the second one it's included at the first line of the `wp_head()` function.

In fact, my `custom_titles()` function worked perfect without the use of the new feature `title-tag`. So it seems the conflict appears when I try to use both.

Do you think it'd be a good solution to put both features in `after_theme_setup` priority 1 in a simple conditional statement, or is there a better way for doing that? It seems the solution should be easier.

---

**UPDATE:** This is crazy. If I remove the `title` tags of the header to use the new feature, the theme-check returns:

> REQUIRED: The theme needs to have  tags, ideally in the
>   header.php file.

If I remove the new feature to use my custom function, the theme-check returns:

> RECOMMENDED: No reference to add_theme_support( "title-tag" ) was
>   found in the theme. It is recommended that the theme implement this
>   functionality for WordPress 4.1 and above.

To be honest: LOL. Adding `add_theme_support` in `functions.php`, and `title` tags in `header.php` as they «RECOMMEND» & «REQUIRE», respectively, it returns always the title twice!

Comment: A hint: When using 'title-tag' support, you can see the source code of `function wp_get_document_title()` - there are the following filters (WP 4.7.3): `pre_get_document_title`, `document_title_separator` and `document_title_parts`. The first one gives full control over the title, instead of specified filter `wp_title` in your question, which now seems obsolete and very soon can get deprecated.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305353/cant-change-the-title-tag-with-wp-title-filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you can not use `wp_title()` in the theme if the theme already supports `title-tag`. The `<head>` of your theme should look like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

The filter and title-tag support:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_functions' );
function theme_functions() {

    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_titles', 10, 2 );
function custom_titles( $title, $sep ) {

    //Check if custom titles are enabled from your option framework
    if ( ot_get_option( 'enable_custom_titles' ) === 'on' ) {
        //Some silly example
        $title = "Some other title" . $title;;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

If you do this, it will work perfectly.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I knew it had to be easier...  I think my mistake was on the custom titles function, without calling the `$title` and `$sep` variables. Let me try it :)

Comment: I've added the checking of `enable_custom_titles` option.

Comment: Is it better to use the checking inside of the function?

Comment: There's one problem: in this function I don't save the titles in variables, I use functions when it's possible, such `the_title();` or `single_tag_title();`... And in variables when it's needed, for example in meta-boxes: `$metatitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metabox_title_tag', true);`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Ok, I will have to change my `custom_titles()` function to get all the values in variables. My solution was faster, but your answer is the right way and I can skip some conditional statements.

Comment: `the_title()`, `single_tag_title()` and son on are template tags, that is, functions intended to be used in template files, not to get information outside template files. For example, if you want to show the title of a post in a template file you can use `the_title()` inside the loop; if you want to get the title of a post outside a template file you could use `get_the_tile( $post_ID )` or a post object returned by `get_post`, `WP_Query`, etc. If you need help with this, please, post another question.

Comment: This answer heads in the right direction, but modern filters should be using `document_title_parts` or `pre_get_document_title` ... see this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305353/cant-change-the-title-tag-with-wp-title-filter

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution, so I'm sure it will be useful for others.

---

### First: custom titles

**Explanation:** If my `custom_titles()` function is enabled, load the function in `functions.php` under the `after_theme_setup` priority 2, and show the `title` tags in the `header.php` file.

In functions.php:

```
if ( ot_get_option( 'enable_custom_titles' ) === 'on' ) {
    // The custom titles function
}
```

In header.php:

```
<?php if ( ot_get_option( 'enable_custom_titles' ) === 'on' ) : ?>
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- The next will return the new WP titles feature if custom titles are off -->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

---

### Then: title-tag support

**Explanation:** If my `custom_titles()` is disabled, `add_theme_support('title-tag');` in `functions.php` under the `after_theme_setup` priority 1.

So, in functions.php:

```
if ( ot_get_option( 'enable_custom_titles' ) === 'off' ) {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
```

About the `after_theme_setup` priority, in my case it's just needed to load the Option-Tree framework before to use the `ot_get_option()` function, so it could be different —not needed— if someone uses a different options framework.

Now my theme has the new titles feature in Version 4.1 and custom titles for SEO using meta-boxes: both available. (I know it is plugin territory, but it's nice to have some essential features —«essential» in my opinion— integrated in the theme). Thanks to this, the clients will have more control on how titles are displayed.