# Attach a custom post type archive to a static page

Tags: custom-post-types

So lets say you have a static home page and your posts page is a page called "Blog" or something along those lines. Using `<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>` in the header.php will then allow the heading of the "Blog" page to show correctly as "Blog" instead of the first post name, and also displays single static pages correctly. How do I go about replicating that for custom post types? I'm trying to avoid using loops in the header.

Comment: Are you talking about document title? (that's is `<title>` element in the HTML). If so, follow @AbhisekMalakar's advise. If your theme supports `title-tag` you have to avoid the direct use of `<title>` in the header.php because it is added by WordPress. If you need to modify it you have to use `wp_title` filter. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176940/add-theme-support-title-tag-in-conflict-with-custom-titles-function/176953#176953) for further information.

Comment: Additionally, as said in the codex, `post_type_archive_title()` is optimized for `archive.php` and `archive-{posttype}.php` template files. It won't output the post type archive title if you use it in a static page.

Comment: @cybmeta I'm not talking about the `<title>` tag (if you actually bothered to read my reply to him) I'm talking about the page title and other data relevant to that page that I can access when I set a static page to display blog posts that I want to replicate for a custom post type

Comment: I read your question and your comments, you can be sure, but it was not clear for me what title you was talking about, that's why I asked. Anyway, as I said, you can not do that using `post_type_archive_title()` in a static page.

Comment: @cybmeta please tell me how "this has nothing to do with the title tag" is unclear to you

Comment: I'm really surprised from your reaction. It was not clear for me and I asked just **trying to help you**, that's all. Where is the problem? You talk about static page, page title, post archive title and header.php. The title in `header.php`, if there is any, is usually the title of the document (that is `<title>`) which can be also referred as "page title". I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
And remove the title tag from your theme, and call the wp_head() at proper place.And let wp handle the title tag for you.

Comment: 1. learn to wrap your code in proper formatting. 2. this has nothing to do with the title tag 3. theme support for title tag already in place 4. `wp_head` is in it's proper place