# Can't change the title tag with wp_title filter

Tags: filters, title

I'm using a theme child of [Ultra Theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/ultra/). This theme is using this :

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

I'd like to customize the title tag of all posts & pages, here is my code :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_custom_title', 10, 2);
function my_custom_title() {
    return("Foo bar");
}
```

The code is not working and I can't figure out why !

Comment: You need to determine whether the theme is the one having the final say. So, you could switch to a default theme, add your function as a plugin, and see whether your function now overrides the title. If not, you have just determined that a plugin is affecting things. SEO plugins often affect the title. If you do find that your function does override the title when you're working with a default theme, then you know for sure it's the theme you are using, and you can search through its files for "title" to narrow it down.

Comment: Try a higher priority than 10 for the filter like 100000.

Comment: @WebElaine i've switched to twentysixteen, added my code to the theme's functions.php and disabled all plugins : the problem remains !

Comment: @NathanJohnson it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 9):

When adding `title-tag` support in a theme, the title tag can be filtered by several filters, but not `wp_title`. The reason is that if the theme supports `title-tag`, WordPress uses [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) instead of [`wp_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/).

For themes with support for `title-tag` you can use [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/):

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'filter_document_title_parts' );
function filter_document_title_parts( $title_parts ) {

    $title_parts['title'] = 'The title'; 
    $title_parts['tagline'] = 'A tagline';
    $title_parts['site'] = 'My Site';

    return $title_parts; 

}
```

Or [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/):

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'filter_document_title' );
function filter_document_title( $title ) {

    $title = 'The title'; 

    return $title; 

}
```

Comment: I've removed my code and put yours (in functions.php) : it doesn't work :(

Comment: If you use the old `wp_title()` function to output the document title, then you must use the old `wp_title` filter. If you support the more recent `title-tag` theme feature, then you must use the new filters you see in this answer. Do not mix them.

Comment: Your Approach helped solve my issue, Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem's root :

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

In functions.php of the child theme I've added this to cancel that function :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_featured_images_from_child_theme', 11 ); 
function remove_featured_images_from_child_theme() {
    remove_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
```

Then I've added this to header.php :

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

With this two snippets of code the wp_title filter works fine.

But I think this is not the right way since WP recommands to use add_theme_support('title-tag'), but I'm disabling it !